# Splitting by character using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string by the char `'-'` along with the spaces to the left and right of it.  How can I do this?

I tried a few things:

```
a.split('[\s]-[\s]')
a.split( *- *)
a.split(\s-\s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
s = 'abc-abc- abc -abc - abc'
r = re.compile('\s*-\s*')
r.split(s)
```

Will give

```
['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc']
```

Comment: This looks like the right (complete) answer to me, and you just beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all spaces around the '-', use this regex.

```
\s*-\s*
```

If you only want one optional space on either side, use this one.

```
\s?-\s?
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know python, only regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
s='one - two - three - four'

print re.split(r'\s*-\s*',s)
```

prints:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```